# skew and change perspective of image and its border going from one direction to another

Tags: html, css

I would like to skew and change perspective of the image (height from top and bottom) going from one direction to another.I am not 100% sure if I am using right terminology but below example should explain what I am trying to achieve.

Example of the image with border:
[image: Image that I have]

Example* of how it should appear on my web page:
[image: Image I would like to show as]

Or another example from reference question
[image: Another example from reference question]

This is what I have tried

- Get the final image and use it as is but the problem is that the
  image quality deteriorates when width is changed.
- Bunch of css options http://jsfiddle.net/6ksayLx8/

```css
/*Attempt 1*/
    #box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        /*background-color:green;*/
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    }
    #box:after, #box:before {
        display: block;
        content:"\0020";
        color: transparent;
        width: 211px;
        height: 45px;
        background: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1px;
        bottom: -20px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }
    #box:before {
        bottom: auto;
        top: -20px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(12deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(12deg);
        transform: rotate(12deg);
    }
    /*Attempt 2*/
     .skew {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        /* the magic ingredient */
        -webkit-transform: skew(-16deg, 0);
        -moz-transform: skew(-16deg, 0);
        -ms-transform: skew(-16deg, 0);
        -o-transform: skew(-16deg, 0);
        transform: skew(-16deg, 0);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
        height: 260px;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
    }
    .skew img {
        -moz-transform: skew(16deg, 0);
        -ms-transform: skew(16deg, 0);
        -o-transform: skew(16deg, 0);
        -webkit-transform: skew(16deg, 0);
        transform: skew(16deg, 0);
        position: relative;
        left: -40px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div id="box">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/560x366" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="skew">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/560x366" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Other details:

- Website uses Bootstrap3 and so the solution should be responsive
- Image must have border
- I am fine not supporting anything less than IE 9

I have gone thru many links and different search terms in Google below are worthy to be mentioned:

- [CSS3 Transform Skew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293736/css3-transform-skew)
- [CSS Skew only container, not content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615492/css-skew-only-container-not-content)
- [CSS Transform maker](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html)

*Please discard the difference of color and scroll bar in this example image. This is just an example to explain outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Today I stumbled upon this article https://viget.com/inspire/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms and it seems to do the task I was looking for (I already moved on with image solution but just pasting this here for others) and live example can be found on https://savingplaces.org/